# How to display chart in android tv using web view(chart.js)

Tags: webview, chart.js, android-tv

I want to display the chart in webview in android tv using the chart.js library.
My problem is HTML file is loaded through webview in android tv or tv-emulator but the chart is not shown in the page I think due to the canvas.I display the content in HTML page

for eg:         <**h1> Hello world <**/h1>

that the above example is shown in android tv. But when I use a canvas tag that was not shown. Is there a way to show chart in web-view.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect perhaps your TV is not HTML5 compliant; the `<canvas>` tag requires HTML5 - however you can export the graph to an image and import that to the page (it will loose it's dynamic changing, and just be a static image) - you'll want to do something like inside this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSgV7/585/ where he generates an image and displays it on-screen (it's not my fiddle).

Good luck!